# how can i stop to kill my application manually by user or android os?

Tags: android

I thought about one android application,so is there possible that user can not kill my android  application manually or android os can not kill my application's process until user uninstalled it?

Do you know how to do that?

If anyone knows than please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

**No that isn't possible.** User always can kill your app and OS also always can kill your app. One you can do is use `onBackPressed()` method to do something on click back button by user.

**EDIT** : You can also create a [background service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), which will relaunch your app on kill, but remember that service is also "killable".

Comment: thanks for your reply but someone tell me that Smart App Protector Free app is there.we can not kill it until we uninstalled it.

Comment: Also Super AppLock app is there.

Comment: it is not possible, but you can create background service

Comment: That's true. It is possible to create service running in background, but it is also "killable".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a background service that will relaunch your application once it is killed by the OS.
Just don't forget to save your data.

**P.S.** This is not how a good application should behave.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but do you know how to create background service?any example or sample code if you have than please help me.

Comment: @CodeProgram: here is the official tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html